# Seemingly very easy Excel unresponsive issue

Tags: excel, vba

So for my code, I don't see why i get my spreadsheet being unresponsive after attempting to do this loop.

function `inpolygon(point, range)` is whether a point(2 cells so (1,2)) fits into a region made out of a range of n by 2.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

```
Public Function whichplay2(point As range, basinrange As range) As String

Dim nbasin As Integer
Dim i As Integer
i = 1

'number of basins = CInt(basinrange.Columns.Count) / 2
nbasin = CInt(basinrange.Columns.Count) / 2

Do While i <= nbasin

If InPolygon(point, range(basinrange.range("A1").Offset(0, 2 * i - 2), _
    basinrange.range("A1").Offset(0, 2 * i - 1).End(xlDown))) = False Then

Else

   whichplay2 = Sheets("RawCoor").range("A1").Offset(0, 2 * i - 2)

End If

Loop


End Function
```

Comment: Please state where exactly you get the error (i.e. which line the debugger points to) and what the inputs are.

Comment: just edited, apologize for my ignorance. the code seems to be correct(i.e. no compile errors) but the excel becomes unresponsive if I run the function. The point refers to a 'point'(lat, long) 'inpolygon' is whether the point fits into the region bounded by 'basinrange'.

Comment: It is still important to know the inputs, the size of the ranges, etc. Did you try stepping through the code with the debugger?

Comment: Umm... just a guess, but the values for both `i` and `nbasin` do not change inside your loop, so the loop will run forever if `i <= nbasin` when it starts.

Comment: @djikay That's it, exactly! `i = i + 1` is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding either `i=i+1` just before the loop, or:

```
For i = 1 To nbasin
*rest of code*
Next i
```